# How do I build a dataframe from a list of tuples and another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` with some information, like this:

```
id   geometry
a1   ...
a2   
a3
```

And I have a function that returns a distance from each ID of the `df` above, like:

```
def radius(gpd_df, cpt, radius):
    sindex = gpd_df.sindex

    bbox = (cpt.geometry.x-radius, 
            cpt.geometry.y-radius, 
            cpt.geometry.x+radius, 
            cpt.geometry.y+radius)

    good = []
    for n in sindex.intersection(bbox):
        dist = cpt.geometry.distance(gpd_df['geometry'][n])
        if dist < radius:
            good.append((dist, n))

    good.sort() 

    return [x for x in good]
```

I use it like

```
test = radius(aa, df.iloc()[0], 0.01)
```

where `aa` is a geopandas data frame, to return

```
[(0.0009698680322606666, 516),
 (0.005197809538642754, 464),
 (0.0058511677467037735, 432),
 (0.006900191591541482, 388),
 (0.009037748834750236, 57)]
```

I would like to build a data frame that looks like

```
a1, 0.0009698680322606666, 516
a1, 0.005197809538642754, 464
a1, 0.0058511677467037735, 432
a1, 0.006900191591541482, 388
a2, 0.009037748834750236, 57
```

*for all points of* `df`

Comment: `np.array(aa)` gives you an np.array, which you could use to turn in to a dataframe.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Yes, thanks. But I'm after taking `df` adding the field `A` and the information returned by the function _for every point_.